# Calculating for Blank Fields and returning a date based on two other columns

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I'm trying to correct the formula that decides if a `ExDate` is blank leave `[YRexpCal` blank, else find the FY of the `ExDate` and return FY as `yy`. My formula is:

```
=IF(([ExDate])="","",IF(MONTH([ExDate])<"10",RIGHT(YEAR([ExDate]),2),RIGHT(YEAR([ExDate])+1,2))
```

the values I've returned are `""` and `"99"`.

The true goal is to take a start date, add `NumYears` return `ExDate` and `FYexpiring`. I keep getting stuck on the first portion.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below formula. Hope it helps.

```
=IF(ISBLANK([ExDate]),"",IF(MONTH([ExDate])<10,RIGHT(YEAR([ExDate]),2),RIGHT(YEAR([ExDate])+1,2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a Formula for you, just some notes of the top of my head:

- Empty dates are interpreted True/False values, so
  `IF([ExDate],HasDate,NoDate)` is the same as `IF([ExDate]="",NoDate,HasDate)`
- `TEXT([Created],"y")` returns: 16
- SharePoint is not strict on types, `TEXT([Created],"y") + 1` returns: 17

All Functions you can use at: https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List